# Ruby string match until "-"

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like `string1 = "foo-bar0164"` and I want store all characters until "-" in a variable. In this example only "foo".

My attempt is:

```
string1.match(/([^-]+)/)
```

But it does match all characters except -.

Comment: Why not simply `string1.split('-').first`?

Comment: Your code is already doing what you want, i.e. capturing `foo` in `foo-bar0164`. If you want to capture the hyphen as well, there is an answer for that below. Otherwise, could you complete your question ?

Comment: *"But it does match all characters except `-`."* -- because there is nothing in your `regex` that matches `-`.

Comment: For this simple use case a `Regexp` is going to be multitudes slower than the `split` suggested by @MarekLipka or other `String` methods like `partition` (similar to the split) or `slice` (e.g. `string1.slice(0,string1.index('-'))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string1.match(/(.*)-/).captures
=> ["foo"]
```

or

```
string1.match(/(.*)-/) { $1 }
=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this straightforward way:

```
> string1.split("-").first
#=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something with a positive lookahead:

```
string1[/\A.*?(?=-)/] #=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to match `/([^-]+)-/`. This will ensure the match ends in the first `-` character.

Answer (score 0):

This Regex will match the pattern [-]

```
^([\w]*)-([\w\d]*)$
```

With the () you can no get the matchgroup 1 and 2 for letters efore the - and after it.

A faster and more common solution would be `string.split("-")[0]` - you will get the first part of it as `String` - but be aware of NullPointers (length should >1 or at least emptystring)

---

I like to check my regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If it is known that the string contains a hyphen

```
str = "1234-567"
str[0,str.index('-)]
  #=> "1234"
```

If not

```
str_len = str.index('-)
str_len ? str[0,str_len] : nil
```

Notice that this method neither uses a regex nor creates a temporary array.